# importing custom class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple master-detail setup with two table view controllers. In the master controller I created a custom class, and I would like to work with this custom class in my detail controller. Now I know swift has done away with implementing classes, but when I try to create a new object of this class in my detail controller, it goes as "undeclared". Should there be an import statement? or am I missing something? here is a preview of the code in my master:

```
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    class Continent {
        var name: String = "Country name"
        var continentCountry: ["countries of selected continent"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your syntax appears incorrect on the line containing `continentCountry`

Comment: that was a copy & paster error , fixed

Comment: That doesn't work either, did you mean `var continentCountry = ["countries of selected continent"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to access `Continent` you'd need to prefix it with `FirstTableViewController`:

```
let continent = FirstTableViewController.Continent()
```

Take a look at [The Swift Programming Language: Nested Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/NestedTypes.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks, I'm still learning swift a little after these years of obj c haha.